# Drawing Rectangles in iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, draw, rectangles

My goal for my app is for the user to be able to sort through different scheduling options by swiping to the left and right of an iPhone screen. How would I draw and remove rectangles as the user sorts through these different scheduling options?

I have a UIViewController.h, UIViewController.m, and UIViewController.xib files to manipulate. Do I need a separate UIView class? If so, how do I connect that UIView class to the view in my .xib file?

Comment: XCode is an application (an IDE). It doesn't draw anything. Objective-C is the programming language for iOS. You may want to check out the tutorials on this site - this one in particular: http://www.raywenderlich.com/2033/core-graphics-101-lines-rectangles-and-gradients (though a second look at your question appears to have little to do with drawing. Maybe you want `UIScrollView`)

Comment: I understand I need to write the objective-c code but I was saying I'm in x-code as a frame of reference. My understanding is the UIScrollView just determines if you can scroll and how far you can scroll. If I drew a rectangle off the screen but had UIScrollView that was defined as being able to scroll that far i could eventually view it. Based on this premise I just need to know how to use the UIViewController and its .xib file to draw rectangles depending on user input to determine coordinates.

Comment: All I need is a method that will take an input determined by the user and draw a rectangle based on the coordinates, height, and width that the user defines.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Wow... so many complicated solution, here is what you need:

```
UIView *myBox  = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(180, 35, 10, 10)];
myBox.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
[self.view addSubview:myBox];
```

Nothing else... don't need to go crazy on the implementation.

Answer (score 12):

```
// 1st Add QuartzCore.framework to your project's "Link Binary with Libraries".

// 2nd Import the header in your .m file (of targeted view controller):

#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

// 3rd Inside - (void)viewDidLoad method:
// Create a UIBezierPath (replace the coordinates with whatever you want):
UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
[path moveToPoint:CGPointMake(10.0, 10.0)];
// # Entry Point with 10px white frame
[path moveToPoint:CGPointMake(10.0, 10.0)];
// # Keeping 10px frame with iPhone's 450 on y-axis
[path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(10.0, 450.0)];
// # Substracting 10px for frame on x-axis, and moving 450 in y-axis
[path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(310.0, 450.0)];
// # Moving up to 1st step 10px line, 310px on the x-axis
[path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(310.0, 10.0)];
// # Back to entry point
[path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(10.0, 10.0)];

// 4th Create a CAShapeLayer that uses that UIBezierPath:
CAShapeLayer *shapeLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
shapeLayer.path = [path CGPath];
shapeLayer.strokeColor = [[UIColor blueColor] CGColor];
shapeLayer.lineWidth = 3.0;
shapeLayer.fillColor = [[UIColor clearColor] CGColor];
Add that CAShapeLayer to your view's layer:

// 5th add shapeLayer as sublayer inside layer view
[self.view.layer addSublayer:shapeLayer];
```

Comment: You could always just do [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:(CGRect)rect];

Answer (score 6):

You can draw a rectangle by using this:

```
 UIBezierPath* rectanglePath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect: CGRectMake(68, 38, 81, 40)];
 [UIColor.grayColor setFill];
 [rectanglePath fill];
```

Answer (score 5):

First Make a CustomView.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MyView : UIView

@end
```

---

```
#import "MyView.h"

@implementation MyView

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}


// Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
// An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    // Drawing Rect
    [[UIColor redColor] setFill];　　　　　　　　　　　　　  // red
    UIRectFill(CGRectInset(self.bounds, 100, 100));
}


@end
```

you test. link to Your AppDelegate or ViewController

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions 
{    
    MyView* view = [[MyView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 30, 300, 400)];
    view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    [window addSubview:view];

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

---

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    MyView* view = [[MyView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 30, 300, 400)];
    view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    [self.view addSubview:view];

    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

A `UIView` happens to draw in the shape of a rectangle, so if all you need is to change the color of the rectangle, set the `backgroundColor` property of the UIView to the color you want it to be.

An empty UIView will do:

```
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, width, height)];
view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

If you are doing it from interface builder, drag a new View from the library onto the canvas and set the background color in the properties of the View.

You probably don't need a custom view for the simple case. You can also add additional items to your "rectangle" view such as UILabels for displaying text.

Comment: This is a suggestion I've seen before but the issue is i need to be able to place a rectangle of literally any size at any coordinate on the screen as the app is running because the user will input the values of the coordinates and the height and width.

Comment: You can dynamically update the frame of any view at run time. But you will need to do that in code. When you update the frame it will change the position and size of the rectangle. It can be "literally any size" and "at any coordinate" :)

Comment: does that include the coordinates of the view? This also needs to be able to have an undefined number of rectangles

Comment: Yes, a `CGRect` specifies both the origin(coordinates) and size. The frame of a view is a `CGRect`.

Comment: What if I need an undefined number of rectangles

Comment: You will need to add them in code one at a time. You can add as many as you want, though if you add too many(hundreds or thousands), you may notice some performance issues.

Comment: Also, I think you mean [UIColor redColor]