# objective-C class to draw rectangle/circle

Tags: ios, drawing, core-graphics

I'm new in Ios programing. I would like to have class to draw and manage rectangle / circle in my view. So i try use solutions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14785311). It works fine when I want to draw one Rectangle, but I would like to have opportunity to draw and manage more Rectangles.
So I add this  to my `CircleManager.h` file:

```
-(void)AddRectangle:(CGRect) rect;
{
//[self drawRect:rect];
[[UIColor blueColor] setFill];
UIRectFill(CGRectInset(self.bounds, 150, 150));
}
```

And in my `ViewControler.m` add this code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {  
CircelManager* view = [[CircelManager alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 30, 300, 400)];  
view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
[view AddRectangle:CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 100)];
[self.view addSubview:view];
[super viewDidLoad];   
}
```

And when I try run this code I get this in my output:

```
Jul 11 13:37:38 SG-MacBook-Air.local NavTry1[1730] <Error>: CGContextSetFillColorWithColor: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.
Jul 11 13:37:38 SG-MacBook-Air.local NavTry1[1730] <Error>: CGContextGetCompositeOperation: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.
Jul 11 13:37:38 SG-MacBook-Air.local NavTry1[1730] <Error>: CGContextSetCompositeOperation: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.
Jul 11 13:37:38 SG-MacBook-Air.local NavTry1[1730] <Error>: CGContextFillRects: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.
Jul 11 13:37:38 SG-MacBook-Air.local NavTry1[1730] <Error>: CGContextSetCompositeOperation: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.
```

I noticed that if I comment line `[self.view addSubview:view];` there is no error.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19599266/invalid-context-0x0-under-ios-7-0-and-system-degradation

Answer (score 0):

You should read the [drawing guide by apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/2ddrawing/conceptual/drawingprintingios/graphicsdrawingoverview/graphicsdrawingoverview.html). After that, I would suggest you create a `CAShapeLayer` (or a view that uses a shape layer as `layerClass`). Set a `UIBezierPath`'s path on the layer. (`UIBezierPath` has convenience methods for creating ovals and rects.).

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting the error is because you are drawing in `viewDidLoad`, which does not have a drawing context. When you call `AddRectangle:` you are attempting to draw, not just storing the coordinates of the rectangle. That function would be better named `drawBlueRect:` or something like that.

To get this to work:

1. Move`AddRectangle:` in your UIView subclass
2. Call`AddRectangle:` from drawRect: in your UIView subclass
3. Remove `AddRectangle:` from your view controller subclass

The second and third parameter to `UIRectInset` will cause the rectangle not to be drawn, because it results in a rectangle with zero width. You are also ignoring the rect parameter in AddRectangle: and always drawing relative to self.bounds.

You should never call `drawRect:` yourself. If you should call `setNeedsDisplay` instead and the graphics context will be configured for you by the time your `drawRect:` override is called. The best practice on iOS is to use CALayers instead of `drawRect:`. Layers are much faster than  `drawRect:`, especially for animations.

I concur with Joride that you should read what he suggested as well as the [Quartz 2D Programming Guide for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/Introduction/Introduction.html). Depending on the level of depth you need, while a bit dated, [Programming with Quartz: 2D and PDF Graphics in Mac OS X](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0123694736) by David Gelphman and Bunny Laden is the definitive guide to Core Graphics.